# Obtener la hora de un pais especifico en javascript

Tags: javascript, date, horas

Quiero obtener la hora de un pais con javascript, de Suiza por ejemplo. Tengo este código, solo me falta lo de obtener la hora de **suiza**:

```javascript
    const time;
    //aqui es donde me falta el código
    var pais = "switzerland"
    document.write("La hora en " + pais + " es: " + time;
```

Agradecería ayuda

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho??

Comment: @OCHOA he intentado esto, pero no funciona. Por eso la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa esto

```js
let date = new Date();
let options = {timeZone: 'Europe/Zurich'};
let time = date.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
console.log('La hora en Zurich es: '+time);
```

Recomendable leer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Switzerland